# How to display distinct values based on MAX date in report builder?

Tags: sql, group-by, reportbuilder3.0, distinct-values, maxdate

I'm quite new to SQL and I hope you can help me.
I'm trying to retrieve unique values from my table based on the latest date where specific users are selected.

This is the data:

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJAf6.png)

And this is what I'm looking to achieve:

[Desired Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWgHb.png)

I tried to write 2 queries but unfortunately:

My 1st query would display duplicated rows for each company:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname ,FilteredAppointment.owneridname ,FilteredAppointment.subject ,MAX(FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart) as Date ,FilteredAppointment.location ,FilteredCcx_member.ccx_mnemonic FROM FilteredAppointment INNER JOIN FilteredAccount ON FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectid = FilteredAccount.accountid INNER JOIN FilteredCcx_member ON FilteredAccount.accountid = FilteredCcx_member.ccx_accountid WHERE FilteredAppointment.statecodename != N'Canceled' AND FilteredAppointment.owneridname IN (N'User1', N'User2', N'User3') GROUP BY FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname ,FilteredAppointment.owneridname ,FilteredAppointment.subject ,FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart ,FilteredAppointment.location ,FilteredCcx_member.ccx_mnemonic ORDER BY FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname
```

And my 2nd query would display one row only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname ,FilteredAppointment.owneridname ,FilteredAppointment.subject ,FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart ,FilteredAppointment.location ,FilteredCcx_member.ccx_mnemonic FROM FilteredAppointment INNER JOIN FilteredAccount ON FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectid = FilteredAccount.accountid INNER JOIN FilteredCcx_member ON FilteredAccount.accountid = FilteredCcx_member.ccx_accountid WHERE FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart = (SELECT MAX(FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart) FROM FilteredAppointment WHERE FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname = FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname) AND  FilteredAppointment.statecodename != N'Canceled' AND FilteredAppointment.owneridname IN (N'User1', N'User2', N'User3') GROUP BY FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname ,FilteredAppointment.owneridname ,FilteredAppointment.subject ,FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart ,FilteredAppointment.location ,FilteredCcx_member.ccx_mnemonic ORDER BY FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue - Thank you for the help again!

```
WITH apptmts AS (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES fa.scheduledstart,fa.location,fa.regardingobjectidname,mem.ccx_mnemonic,fa.owneridname,fa.subject FROM FilteredAppointment fa JOIN FilteredAccount acc on fa.regardingobjectid = acc.accountid JOIN FilteredCcx_member mem ON acc.accountid = mem.ccx_accountid WHERE fa.statecodename != N'Canceled' AND fa.owneridname IN (N'User1', N'User2', N'User3') ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fa.regardingobjectidname ORDER BY fa.scheduledstart DESC) ) SELECT * FROM apptmts ORDER BY scheduledstart DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT distinct a.date, a.company, a.companyID, a.User,  a.Location, a.topic
    FROM tablename a
    inner join
    (
    Select company, companyID, User, max(date) as recent_date
    from
    tablename 
    group by company, companyID, User
    ) b
    on a.date=b.recent_date and a.company=b.company and a.companyID=b.companyID
    and a.User=b.User;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the response, much appreciated! Like I said I'm new to SQL - still learning. It tells me invalid column for the company ID. I had to do a join with company and company ID